# How do you match a Stripe Checkout to a charge.succeeded webhook?

Tags: stripe-payments

We are using the Stripe Checkout and setting our metadata when we create the Session. This allows us to catch the checkout.session.completed webhook and that webhook contains the metadata.

However, we also use Sources, like WeChat, and these are not handled by the Stripe Checkout. To use WeChat, we create a Source and when the user confirms via the QR code, we charge it.

We want to use the charge.succeeded webhook as a central place to fulfil orders, regardless of where they come.

**The issue is that the charge.succeeded webhook generated from a successful Stripe Checkout does not contain any of the Session metadata we set, so we can't link it to a Checkout Session and hence have no idea what it relates to**

The only way we can see how to do this is:

**Stripe Checkout**

Catch the checkout.session.completed webhook and use the included metadata to fulfil the order. For the customer details, we can call the Payment Intent

**WeChat (And other sources)**

Catch the charge.succeeded webhook which contains both the customer data and the Source, which contains the metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Charge object will have a [payment_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-payment_intent) and you can [list CheckoutSessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent) by that PaymentIntent's id.

Alternatively, you can also set the `metadata` [directly on the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) when creating the CheckoutSession.

Comment: payment_intent_data may be the answer, thank you!

Comment: Just looping back, payment_intent_data is the way to go with this and can confirm it works.

Comment: Thanks worked. So in PHP this worked `$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET')); $session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->all(['payment_intent' => 'pi_....'])->first();`